# "Запекание" некорректно выдает размеры текстуры

Tags: blender, текстура

Я конструирую дом. Натянул на все стены и на пол текстуры, и дело в том, что к каждой стене и полу сделал индивидуальный размер текстуры (они же сами разного размера), чтобы они все были одинаковы. Например : нацепил на стену текстуру кирпичей, а они выглядят слишком огромными по отношению к другим стенам. Решил я это расширив площадь между "вершинами" в UV mappingе, и кирпичи уменьшались.
    Так вот, теперь когда я выделяю всю сцену, делаю автоматическую развертку в UV и захожу запечь все это - после запекания эти текстуры выглядят такими же неестественно большими и размеры, которые я задавал, не сохранились. Как исправить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделайте еще одну UV развертку для запекания, объект может содержать несколько разверток:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]